# How to find the number of Distinct ID's on one table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT  Count(Teams.Name)
    , Teams.TeamID
    , Teams.Name 
FROM Teams, Rosters 
WHERE Rosters.TeamID = Teams.TeamID
```

Is my query so far. I'd like it to print the number of entries of Rosters.TeamID that correspond to Teams.TeamID.

Comment: First I'll suggest that you switch to ANSI joins.

Comment: Thanks @alexherm !

Comment: Would there ever be a situation where a `TeamID` in `Rosters` did not match a `TeamID` in `Teams`? If there is a basic amount of RI in this database, counting `DISTINCT` `TeamID` values in `Rosters` — without using any `JOIN` — should be suffcient 

Comment: @matigo Yes, There are some teams that do not have a TeamID value in Rosters but do in Teams

Comment: If the `TeamID` value in `Rosters` is `NULL` it will be excluded from a `COUNT(DISTINCT TeamID)`. Alternatively, some conditionals could be thrown in to handle DB design decisions `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN IFNULL(TeamID, 0) > 0 THEN TeamID ELSE NULL END)` ... but then you start getting into ugly code just to save an index lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query you want is:

```
SELECT t.TeamID, t.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM Teams t JOIN
     Rosters r
     ON r.TeamID = t.TeamID
GROUP BY t.TeamID, t.Name;
```

Basically, your query is missing the `GROUP BY`, but you should also learn proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: What does the join accomplish here? If you removed the join and left the group by, would this logically end up being identical to what you have posted?

Comment: @TaylorV . . . The accepted answer is incorrect in many different ways.  I figured there should be a correct answer, both syntactically and logically, for the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you so much for your answer. I had just accepted the previous answer without actually testing as this is purely a homework assignment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh apologies, I wasn't questioning your solution. For my own knowledge, I was just asking what the join is doing in this query given that nothing is being selected from `Rosters r` table. I'm still not sure if I understand.

Comment: @TaylorV . . . The additional rows are being generated due to the `JOIN`.  That is what is being counted.  I can see how this might be confusing to someone learning SQL.